# Loading SLD style (*.SLD) for vector layer in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, sld

I'm writing a PyQGIS script for loading a set of vector layers in QGIS, and for them I have fixed SLD styles, how can I style them in the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load your SLD style  with

```py
yourlayer = QgsVectorLayer('path_to_shp.shp', "Layer name", "ogr")
yourlayer.loadSldStyle('path_to_your_sld_file.sld')
```